# How to get items to stretch to fill width?

Tags: css, grid-layout, css-grid

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 100px);
  grid-gap: 3px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

How can I stretch the red `item` boxes a little bit so that they fill the entire width of the green `container` box?

They should all be the same width, and a little bit bigger than 100px.

The last row should be left-aligned as it is now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to add a *fraction unit* to the `grid-template-columns` rule.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
```

This rule creates as many columns as will fit in the container.

The minimum width of each column is 100px.

The maximum width is `1fr`, which means the column will consume any free space on the row.

Now all horizontal space in the container is being used.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 3px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

These posts explain the solution above in more detail:

- [Equal width flex items even after they wrap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44154580/3597276)
- [The difference between percentage and fr units in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090726/3597276)

Comment: Is there a difference between `1fr` and `auto` in this context? It sounds like "auto" might make the column-widths uneven but that doesn't appear to be the case.

Comment: The column widths are not uneven because the minimum width for each column is fixed at 100px, and *there is no content in the items*, which is the basis for `auto`.

Comment: Ah..okay. Thanks! In my real usage the content *does* differ but it wasn't redistributing, I guess because I have `overflow: hidden`? Anyway.. doesn't matter, this is perfect. Thanks again!