# Prevent grid items from expanding when content is added

Tags: html, css, grid-layout, css-grid

I'm trying to create a layout where the screen is divided into some number of equally-sized cells. When I fill one of the cells with content, it stretches to be larger than the other cells, even though the content is much smaller than the cell itself.

Why is the cell stretching despite it being plenty big to hold its content? How can I prevent it from resizing?

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #880022;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 20px auto 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto 20px;
}

#content2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}

#grid {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 2px 2px;
}

.tile {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tile span {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.tile:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="tile"><span>test</span></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the column and row sizes to `auto`. This means they will be sized based on their content. Instead, [use `fr` units](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090726/3597276), which use the free space in the container.

```css
#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 20px auto 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #880022;
}

#grid {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;     /* adjustment */
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;  /* adjustment */
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.tile {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
}

.tile:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

.tile span {
  font-size: 2em;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="grid">
    <div class="tile"><span>test</span></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
    <div class="tile"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/720pguyw/)

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of extra markup, here is a simplified version, the trick is using `fr` unit instead of `auto` and  you can use `repeat()`

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #802;
}

#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, minmax(80px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 2px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100vh
}

.tile {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.tile span {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.tile:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="tile"><span>test</span></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
  <div class="tile"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to give **[`line-height: 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)** to your `.tile` elements. This will ensure that the text doesn't take up any space, though will limit you to only having one line of text per square:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #880022;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 20px auto 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto 20px;
}

#content2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}

#grid {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 2px 2px;
}

.tile {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

.tile span {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.tile:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="grid">
      <div class="tile"><span>test</span></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

However, in my opinion, the *better* solution would be to set **[`grid-auto-rows: 1fr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows)** on `#grid`, which instructs each of the rows to take up as much height as the tallest row:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #880022;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: 20px auto 20px;
  grid-template-columns: 20px auto 20px;
}

#content2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}

#grid {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-gap: 2px 2px;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
}

.tile {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  line-height: 0;
}

.tile span {
  font-size: 2em;
}

.tile:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="grid">
      <div class="tile"><span>test</span></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
      <div class="tile"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Would be interested to know why this was down-voted considering it provides two different solutions to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try

max-width:something px;
max-height:something px;

inside #grid.