# Make a CSS Grid fit the minimum amount of space

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have something like this :

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.otherstuff {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 10px 10px;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='stuff'>Stuff</div>
  <div class='otherstuff'>
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class='cell'>Cell 1</div>
      <div class='cell'>Cell 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like the grid to take up only the *minimal* amount of space required, and not to stretch out. I've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49339649/make-grid-rows-take-up-minimum-space) and saw that it was possible with `grid-template-columns` and `auto` values, but is there a way to do it without knowing the number of children in advance ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `grid-auto-columns: min-content` or `grid-auto-columns: max-content`, this property will affect only columns with the size not set.

> The `grid-auto-columns` CSS property specifies the size of an implicitly-created grid column track.

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.otherstuff {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 10px 10px;
  grid-auto-columns: max-content;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='stuff'>Stuff</div>
  <div class='otherstuff'>
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class='cell'>Cell 1</div>
      <div class='cell'>Cell 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nop, that makes it too small.

Comment: so, instead of `grid-auto-columns: min-content` you have to use `grid-auto-columns: max-content` as you can see I have updated my answer

Answer (score 7):

You can use `inline-grid` - see demo below:

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}

.otherstuff {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-grid; /* changed */
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 10px 10px;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='stuff'>Stuff</div>
  <div class='otherstuff'>
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class='cell'>Cell 1</div>
      <div class='cell'>Cell 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, that was a quick fix. Thank you ! (I need to wait 9 minutes before accepting your answer)

Comment: @Strebler "*and saw that it was possible with grid-template-columns and auto values, but is there a way to do it without knowing the number of children in advance*" => you can use `grid-auto-columns: auto` to specify *auto* on all columns without specifying `grid-template-columns` (that will be your *implicit grid*)...

Comment: @Strebler even if you specify *auto* it stretches as you have `flex-grow` on the wrapper...

Comment: Yep, `grid-auto-columns` doesn't work because of that. I'll stick with `inline-grid`.

Answer (score 2):

Do the `flex-grow: 0` in `otherstuff` class. See below:

```css
.row {
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
}

.otherstuff {
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
  gap: 10px 10px;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class='stuff'>Stuff</div>
  <div class='otherstuff'>
    <div class='grid'>
      <div class='cell'>Cell 1</div>
      <div class='cell'>Cell 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would like to do it without changing that. `inline-grid` did the trick.