# How do I make the first grid item span 100%?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have the following for desktop, which creates 4 equal columns all at 25%.

```css
.footer-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-inner">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
</div>
```

However, how can I resize these in a media query to make the first column go 100% and the rest of the columns naturally wrap underneath and now be 33.333% still using CSS grids?

```
.footer-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100% 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
  /* AND THIS */
  grid-template-columns: 100% 33.333% 33.333% 33.333%;
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Change the grid to three columns and set the first div to span them all at the appropriate point.

```css
.footer-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.footer-inner div {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-inner :first-child {
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-inner">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome answer, I would add for any Magento developers (yes it's a bit tenuous) that if you want to do this with `.lib-css()` you should use `grid-column-start, 1` and `grid-column-end, -1` instead of the `grid-column` shorthand

Comment: what does the -1 mean?

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with the `grid-column: span 3` set on the `:first-child`:

```css
.footer-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
}

@media (max-width: 650px) {
  .footer-inner {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
  .footer-inner > div:first-child {
    grid-column: span 3;
    border: 1px solid;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-inner">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a very simple method. You only need three lines of code.

*For wide screens:*

```css
.footer-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
}

.footer-inner > div {
  grid-row: 1;
}



/* non-essential demo styles */
.footer-inner { background-color: gray; grid-gap: 1px; }
.footer-inner > div { background-color: lightgreen; text-align: center; padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="footer-inner">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
</div>
```

*For narrow screens:*

```css
.footer-inner {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
}

.footer-inner > div:first-child {
  grid-column: span 3;
}



/* non-essential demo styles */
.footer-inner { background-color: gray; grid-gap: 1px; }
.footer-inner > div { background-color: lightgreen; text-align: center; padding: 5px;}
```

```html
<div class="footer-inner">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
</div>
```

**Explanations**

*wide screens*

The [**`grid-auto-columns`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns) property sets the width of implicit columns. By setting the value to `1fr`, all columns created will consume an equal distribution of free space in the row. With `grid-row: 1` applied to all items they will appear on the first row.

*narrow screens*

Once you set the first item to span three implicit columns the container must create three columns. The remaining items can then fit neatly underneath in the newly-created columns.

---

Lastly, consider using `fr` units instead of percentages (like 33.33%) in your track sizing. Then you don't have to worry about factoring in margins and grid gaps. Here's some more info: [The difference between percentage and fr units in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090726/3597276)