# Increasing image width across different section tags?

Tags: html, css

I am currently using grid for a personnal project. I need help resizing my images width when in desktop view to fit all of the page width instead of taking half of it.

I need the image to go from [this](https://d2w9rnfcy7mm78.cloudfront.net/4017440/original_9e01a21be83bbdaf5d2201f4734d40ba.png) to this [desired outcome](https://d2w9rnfcy7mm78.cloudfront.net/4017441/original_f4ce4aefc7be5a29154c2774ca0f02ec.png) but I can't figure it out on my own.

Here's a code snippet of the issue :

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: default;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
}

html,
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;

}

::selection {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 1.5rem 0 0 2rem;
    background:#000;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #777;
}

a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #777;
}

a[href]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #444;
}

h1,
.h1,
h4,
.h4 {
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #000;
}

h1,
.h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #fff;
}

h4,
.h4 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0 0 .75rem;
    color: #fff;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 2rem;
}

dd {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 .25rem;
}

.shell {
    grid-template-columns: 44rem 15rem 15rem;
    grid-column-gap: 4rem;
    display: grid;
}

.widget {
    margin: 0 0 2.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .shell {
        grid-template-columns: 24rem;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-column-gap: 0;
        grid-row-gap: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .shell {
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        padding: 1.5rem 1.25rem 0;
        font-size: 1.0625rem;
    }
    h4,
    .h4 {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
}


.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta content="A product designer and full-stack developer from the UK." name="description">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Studying design and business at Griffith University in tropical Brisbane, Australia.">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Noel Emmanuel">
    <link href="./info_files/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>NOEL EMMANUEL - INFO</title>
</head>

<body
 class="shell">
    <section>
        <header>
            <h1>Site header</h1></header>
        <p class="h2">a design student in Brisbane, Australia.</p>

    </section>
    <section>
        <dl class="widget"><dt class="h4">Things I can do</dt>
            <dd>Visual Design, Art Direction, Branding, Websites, Event Design, Identity, Naming, Print, Writing, Design Strategy, Social Media & Typography.</dd>
        </dl>
       
        
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="widget">
            <h4>Contact</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">Email</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://instagram.com/kevin/">Insta</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <img class="responsive" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jCwIvz3ezcA/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="image 1" vspace="18">
        <img class="responsive" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jCwIvz3ezcA/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="image 2" vspace="18">
        <img class="responsive" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jCwIvz3ezcA/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="image 3" vspace="18">
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Here's the issue on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oL36rupk/1/) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is adding new width for section with images not an option?

```
//html
<section id="img-sec">

//css
#img-sec {
  width: 82rem;
}

#my-img {
  width: 40rem;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: It works but I need to center the image. Because there is extra space on the right.

Comment: If the img is not 100% width then you can center it with
`#img {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 40rem;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Simply set this CSS to your sections when in desktop view : `grid-column: span 3;` or `grid-column: 1 / -1;`.

Next time, be a bit more thorough with your research, you could have found this duplicate of your question that answers it pretty well already : [How do I make the first grid item span 100%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50447477/how-do-i-make-the-first-grid-item-span-100)

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: default;
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
}

html,
body {
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;

}

::selection {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}

body {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 1.5rem 0 0 2rem;
    background:#000;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.4;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: #777;
}

a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #777;
}

a[href]:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #444;
}

h1,
.h1,
h4,
.h4 {
    font-weight: 400;
    margin-top: 0;
    color: #000;
}

h1,
.h1 {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #fff;
}

h4,
.h4 {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin: 0 0 .75rem;
    color: #fff;
}

p {
    margin: 0 0 2rem;
}

dd {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 .25rem;
}

.shell {
    grid-template-columns: 44rem 15rem 15rem;
    grid-column-gap: 4rem;
    display: grid;
}

.widget {
    margin: 0 0 2.5rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {

    section {
        grid-column: span 3;
        /* grid-column: 1 / -1; works as well */
    }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .shell {
        grid-template-columns: 24rem;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-column-gap: 0;
        grid-row-gap: 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    .shell {
        grid-template-columns: 100%;
        padding: 1.5rem 1.25rem 0;
        font-size: 1.0625rem;
    }
    h4,
    .h4 {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }
}


.responsive {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta content="A product designer and full-stack developer from the UK." name="description">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Studying design and business at Griffith University in tropical Brisbane, Australia.">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Noel Emmanuel">
    <link href="./info_files/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>NOEL EMMANUEL - INFO</title>
</head>

<body
 class="shell">
    <section>
        <header>
            <h1>Site header</h1></header>
        <p class="h2">a design student in Brisbane, Australia.</p>

    </section>
    <section>
        <dl class="widget"><dt class="h4">Things I can do</dt>
            <dd>Visual Design, Art Direction, Branding, Websites, Event Design, Identity, Naming, Print, Writing, Design Strategy, Social Media & Typography.</dd>
        </dl>
       
        
    </section>
    <section>
        <div class="widget">
            <h4>Contact</h4>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="mailto:email@gmail.com">Email</a></li>
                <li><a href="https://instagram.com/kevin/">Insta</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section>
        <img class="responsive" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jCwIvz3ezcA/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="image 1" vspace="18">
        <img class="responsive" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jCwIvz3ezcA/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="image 2" vspace="18">
        <img class="responsive" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jCwIvz3ezcA/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="image 3" vspace="18">
    </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code on JSFiddle, I found that you should use this code:

```css
#img-section {
    width: 82rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .shell {
        grid-template-columns: 24rem;
        grid-template-rows: auto;
        grid-column-gap: 0;
        grid-row-gap: 0;
    }

    #img-section {
      width: 24rem;
    }
}
```

```html
<section id="img-section">
<img class="responsive" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jCwIvz3ezcA/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="image 1" vspace="18">
<img class="responsive" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jCwIvz3ezcA/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="image 2" vspace="18">
<img class="responsive" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/jCwIvz3ezcA/maxresdefault.jpg" alt="image 3" vspace="18">
</section>
```

In this matter, you'll be using all the full width for the images section:

`44rem + 4rem + 15rem + 4rem + 15rem = 82rem`

These are values of `.shell` on the `grid-template-columns` property.

Hope this is what you were achieving for.