# CSS grid with padding overflows container

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-grid

I am trying to create a footer whose width is 100% (of the body). On the left side of the footer, I want a logo. On the right side of the footer, I want some text. So I decided to try to use CSS grid.

This is almost exactly what I'm going for:

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #2D1975;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 30% 70%;
}

.footerGridLogo {
  background-color: red;
}

.footerGridQuestions {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footerGridLogo"></div>
  <div class="footerGridQuestions"></div>
</div>
```

However, I want to add some padding to the left of the grid, let's say 10%, so that the logo isn't so close to the left edge. So instead of a 30-70 split, I try a 10-25-65 split. However, the grid ends up overflowing. Why is that?

Demonstration of the issue:

```css
.footer {
  background-color: #2D1975;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  display: grid;
  padding-left: 10%;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 65%;
}

.footerGridLogo {
  background-color: red;
}

.footerGridQuestions {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footerGridLogo">
  </div>
  <div class="footerGridQuestions">
  </div>
</div>
```

I realize that just adding another grid item of 10% instead of padding solves my problem, but I'm curious why padding doesn't work the same way.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First, instead of using percentage units use `fr` units. These units represent leftover space and are factored in *after* fixed lengths (such as padding) have been rendered.

So instead of this:

```
grid-template-columns: 30% 70%
```

Try this:

```
grid-template-columns: 3fr 7fr
```

More details:

- [The difference between percentage and fr units in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090726/3597276)

---

Second, remove the `width: 100%` on the container.

```
.footer {
  background-color: #2D1975;
  width: 100%; <---------- remove
  height: 350px;
  display: grid;
  padding-left: 10%;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 65%;
}
```

When you set the `.footer` to `display: grid` it becomes (or remains) a block-level element. Such elements automatically occupy the full width of the parent.

However, if you add `width: 100%` to a block-level element it then adds any padding, margin and border to the calculation, resulting in an overflow. So just remove it.

---

Third, this whole problem can be avoided if you add the `padding-left` to the logo itself, and not to the grid container or grid item.

Comment: what could width: 100% be replaced with, if the grid should fill the parent?

Comment: See Grid's "line-based placement" features. In particular, the `grid-column` shorthand property. For example: `grid-column: 1 / -1` in an explicit grid.

Comment: Removing the `width: 100%;` worked for me.

Answer (score 13):

This is [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).

The default value is `content-box`, which means that `padding` and `border` values are added to the `width`.

You can change this to `border-box`, which includes `padding` and `border` in the width.

Here is a common approach, [from this article](https://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/):

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #2D1975;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  display: grid;
  padding-left: 10%;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 65%;
}

.footerGridLogo {
  background-color: red;
}

.footerGridQuestions {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footerGridLogo">
  </div>
  <div class="footerGridQuestions">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Be careful with this approach. It screwed up the `width` of my project pages and `laravel mix (+ vuejs)` couldn't detect it. Only removing it and an `IDE restart` fixed the problem.

Comment: How does restarting your IDE relate to changing a CSS property?

Comment: Don't ask me. If you use phpstorm with a Filewatcher, there might be a way for it to relate.

Comment: Just wanted to say, that instead of adding `box-sizing` to the `html element` you can add it to whatever you want and it works. Thanks @sol

Answer (score 3):

I fixed css-grid / padding problems adding next code to css:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever tried to remove this line

```
    width: 100%;
```

from your CSS code?

Just try and see the result.

Answer (score 1):

When you do padding of an HTML element it displaces the content (actually creates space) with respect to its border [image]

When you do 10% padding-left to your footer, the content displaces by 10% from the left border. But you have 25% and 65% grid ratio which totals to 90%. The rest of 10% is background.

To resolve this issue use a ratio of 25% and 75% or any ratio which totals to 100%. Still the padding will cause the total width to overflow by 10%.
So set the width of the footer to 90% that must resolve the overflow problem.

```css
.footer {
 background-color: #2D1975;
 width: 90%;
 height: 350px;
 display: grid;
    padding-left:10%;
     grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
    }
    
    .footerGridLogo {
     background-color: red;
    }
    
    .footerGridQuestions {
     background-color: green;
    }
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="footerGridLogo">
  </div>
  <div class="footerGridQuestions">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers helped me with my problem. My `grid` would screw up the `grid-width` if I added `padding`. The only thing that helped me was to create a `padding div` inside the `grid columns` around the `grid content`:

```
<div class="grid">
  <div class="pad">
    content...
  </div>
</div>

<style lang="scss">
.grid {
    display: grid;
    .pad {
      padding: 1vw;
      content-styles...
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are padding 10% left of the div and then assigning the width to be 100% this is causing a %110 total including the padding.

Pad in the div above the footer and assign the contents of the child div to 100%

```
.container {
  padding: 10px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #2D1975;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 65%;
}

.footerGridLogo {
  background-color: red;
}

.footerGridQuestions {
  background-color: green;
}

<div class="container"> 
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="footerGridLogo"></div>
    <div class="footerGridQuestions"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```