# CSS - Prevent div content from resizing parent

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a grid of boxes that I want to display some content on. However, I would also like for all of them to be the same size (scaled according to window size).

I have the following code:

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-block {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 16% 0 16%;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-block">1</div>
  <div class="grid-block">2</div>
  <div class="grid-block">3</div>
  <div class="grid-block">4</div>
  <div class="grid-block">5</div>
  <div class="grid-block">6</div>
  <div class="grid-block">7</div>
  <div class="grid-block">8</div>
  <div class="grid-block">9</div>
</div>
```

Here, if I replace any of the numbers in my "grid-block" divs with some text, the whole box and all boxes along the same column get resized.

I would like to force all boxes to be the same size (scaled as the window grows or shrinks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Grid_Layout#The_fr_Unit):

> The fr unit as a unit which represents a fraction of the available
>   space in the grid container.

Swapping `auto` with `fr`s solves your problem.

**Edit:** For the height to remain equal (but not fixed), I'm using the `minmax` function. I'm telling the grid that each cell must be *at least* its default size of `auto` and, at most, 1 equal fraction of the grid. The result is what you're after. If one cell contains a lot of text and grows quite a bit, the other cells will be fractionally equivalent to whatever the largest cell has grown to.

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, minmax(auto, 1fr));
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-block {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 16% 0 16%;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-block">1</div>
  <div class="grid-block">Lots of text in here</div>
  <div class="grid-block">3</div>
  <div class="grid-block">Lots and lots and lots and lots of text in here as well</div>
  <div class="grid-block">5</div>
  <div class="grid-block">6</div>
  <div class="grid-block">7</div>
  <div class="grid-block">8</div>
  <div class="grid-block">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to define `width` and `height`  for the `grid-block` or the boxes like this

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-block {
  border: 1px solid;
  /*here*/
  width:300px;
  height:70px;
  padding: 16% 0 16%;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-block">Some random textSome random text</div>
  <div class="grid-block">Some random textSome random textSome random textSome random text</div>
  <div class="grid-block">Some random textSome random text</div>
  <div class="grid-block">Some random textSome random textSome random textSome random textSome random textSome random textSome random textSome random textSome random textSome random textSome random textSome random text</div>
  <div class="grid-block">5</div>
  <div class="grid-block">6</div>
  <div class="grid-block">7</div>
  <div class="grid-block">8</div>
  <div class="grid-block">9</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `fr` unit instead of `auto` for your `grid-template-columns`

Learn more about the FR unit [HERE!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090726/the-difference-between-percentage-and-fr-units-in-css-grid-layout)

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-block {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 16% 0 16%;
  margin: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-block">1asdfasdfsadasdfa asdfas asd a adsa</div>
  <div class="grid-block">2</div>
  <div class="grid-block">3</div>
  <div class="grid-block">4</div>
  <div class="grid-block">5</div>
  <div class="grid-block">6</div>
  <div class="grid-block">7</div>
  <div class="grid-block">8</div>
  <div class="grid-block">9</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, this does the trick for width... Is there a similar way to control the height so all boxes are also the same height?