# Why is my css grid not enclosing its child elements?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to create two 4 by 6 grids nested inside of a 1 by 2 grid. The outermost grid is not containing the children grids. So they are semi collapsing in over each other.

This should be fairly easy.

I've gone through this site:

- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

I've gone through youtube tutorials.

I've also tried these tools:

- https://grid.layoutit.com/
- https://cssgrid-generator.netlify.com/

I've tried setting columns and rows with fr, %, and px.

I've tried using line numbers, and area. etc.

```css
#outside {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 10%;
  //grid-row-gap: 300px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 20%);
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
  grid-gap: 8px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="outside">

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="item i1a">1</div>
        <div class="item i2a">2</div>
        <div class="item i3a">3</div>
        <div class="item i4a">4</div>
        <div class="item i5a">5</div>
        <div class="item i6a">6</div>
        <div class="item i7a">7</div>
        <div class="item i8a">8</div>
        <div class="item i9a">9</div>
        <div class="item i10a">10</div>
        <div class="item i11a">11</div>
        <div class="item i12a">12</div>
        <div class="item i13a">13</div>
        <div class="item i14a">14</div>
        <div class="item i15a">15</div>
        <div class="item i16a">16</div>
        <div class="item i17a">17</div>
        <div class="item i18a">18</div>
        <div class="item i19a">19</div>
        <div class="item i20a">20</div>
        <div class="item i21a">21</div>
        <div class="item i22a">22</div>
        <div class="item i23a">23</div>
        <div class="item i24a">24</div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
        <div class="item i1b">1</div>
        <div class="item i2b">2</div>
        <div class="item i3b">3</div>
        <div class="item i4b">4</div>
        <div class="item i5b">5</div>
        <div class="item i6b">6</div>
        <div class="item i7b">7</div>
        <div class="item i8b">8</div>
        <div class="item i9b">9</div>
        <div class="item i10b">10</div>
        <div class="item i11b">11</div>
        <div class="item i12b">12</div>
        <div class="item i13b">13</div>
        <div class="item i14b">14</div>
        <div class="item i15b">15</div>
        <div class="item i16b">16</div>
        <div class="item i17b">17</div>
        <div class="item i18b">18</div>
        <div class="item i19b">19</div>
        <div class="item i20b">20</div>
        <div class="item i21b">21</div>
        <div class="item i22b">22</div>
        <div class="item i23b">23</div>
        <div class="item i24b">24</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: 6 rows of 20% heights each + a gap is more than a 100% : here 
  `grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 20%);` is probably the issue and theres is probably no need either to add this rule, If you want to keep it 
  `grid-template-rows: repeat(6, auto);` or 
  `grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);` will do better imho.

Comment: I already tried repeat(6, 1fr);

Answer (score 1):

There is no height defined on your grid containers. This creates two problems:

1. On the primary container, without a defined height, the height is determined by its content. Therefore, there is no extra space available and `1fr` doesn't do anything. So you may as well switch to `auto` in your `grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr)` rule.
2. On the nested containers, without a defined height, 20% on the rows will render unreliably / quirky across browsers because the browser doesn't know: *20% of what?* Therefore, either define a height on the container (knowing that 6 * 20% will overflow) or switch to `auto` in your `grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 20%)` rule.

These posts may also help you understand the forces at work here:

- [Working with the CSS `height` property and percentage values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276)
- [Why heights need to be defined, but not widths](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276)
- [The difference between percentage and fr units in CSS Grid Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45090726/3597276)

---

```css
#outside {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, auto); /* adjustment */
  /* grid-auto-rows: 10%; */
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  background-color: red;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(6, auto); /* adjustment */
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
  grid-gap: 8px; /* creates space between grid items only; "gutters" */
  padding: 8px;  /* creates space between container and items */
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: green;
}

.item {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="outside">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item i1a">1</div>
    <div class="item i2a">2</div>
    <div class="item i3a">3</div>
    <div class="item i4a">4</div>
    <div class="item i5a">5</div>
    <div class="item i6a">6</div>
    <div class="item i7a">7</div>
    <div class="item i8a">8</div>
    <div class="item i9a">9</div>
    <div class="item i10a">10</div>
    <div class="item i11a">11</div>
    <div class="item i12a">12</div>
    <div class="item i13a">13</div>
    <div class="item i14a">14</div>
    <div class="item i15a">15</div>
    <div class="item i16a">16</div>
    <div class="item i17a">17</div>
    <div class="item i18a">18</div>
    <div class="item i19a">19</div>
    <div class="item i20a">20</div>
    <div class="item i21a">21</div>
    <div class="item i22a">22</div>
    <div class="item i23a">23</div>
    <div class="item i24a">24</div>
  </div>
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="item i1b">1</div>
    <div class="item i2b">2</div>
    <div class="item i3b">3</div>
    <div class="item i4b">4</div>
    <div class="item i5b">5</div>
    <div class="item i6b">6</div>
    <div class="item i7b">7</div>
    <div class="item i8b">8</div>
    <div class="item i9b">9</div>
    <div class="item i10b">10</div>
    <div class="item i11b">11</div>
    <div class="item i12b">12</div>
    <div class="item i13b">13</div>
    <div class="item i14b">14</div>
    <div class="item i15b">15</div>
    <div class="item i16b">16</div>
    <div class="item i17b">17</div>
    <div class="item i18b">18</div>
    <div class="item i19b">19</div>
    <div class="item i20b">20</div>
    <div class="item i21b">21</div>
    <div class="item i22b">22</div>
    <div class="item i23b">23</div>
    <div class="item i24b">24</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tvoqnsb6/)