# Why does Firefox show this grid layout differently than Chromium?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, chromium

I'm trying to build a very simple grid layout that should show some containers, aligned like so:

[image]

The screenshot is from Chromium, which seems to be working as intended. If I activate the grid inspector, I can see the row tracks laid out as expected:

[image]

This screenshot is from Firefox:

[image]

Here's a screenshot of the grid inspector:

[image]

The middle tracks seem... compressed.

I found [this Firefox bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1609495), not sure if it's related.

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div align="center" id="container">
        <div id="helpContainer">
            <div>H E L P</div>
            <div>J: left</div>
            <div>K: rotate</div>
            <div>L: right</div>
            <div>space: drop</div>
        </div>
        <div id="gameContainer">
        </div>
        <div id="speedContainer">
            <div>S P E E D</div>
            <span id="current-speed">0</span>
        </div>
        <div id="scoreContainer">
            <div>S C O R E</div>
            <div>
                <span>Best:</span>
                <span id="high-score"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="score">
                <span>Current:</span>
                <span id="current-score">0</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
#gameContainer, #scoreContainer, #helpContainer, #speedContainer {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 35% 30% 35%;
    grid-template-rows: 20% 30% 30% 20%;
    justify-items: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#helpContainer {
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 2;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 4;
}

#gameContainer {
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    grid-row-start: 1;
    grid-row-end: 5;
    width: 500px;
    height: 900px;
}

#speedContainer {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 2;
    grid-row-end: 3;
}

#scoreContainer {
    grid-column-start: 3;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-row-start: 3;
    grid-row-end: 4;
}
```

[JSFiddle fullscreen view](https://jsfiddle.net/jb0fL98k/show)

[JSFiddle editor](https://jsfiddle.net/jb0fL98k/)

Comment: reminded me of this right off the bat: https://www.vice.com/en/article/a359vz/purecss-amazing-image-made-of-code-looks-different-based-on-your-browser

Comment: [Difference between percentage and fr units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45090726/the-difference-between-percentage-and-fr-units-in-css-grid-layout). If you go with fr, it should work